# django. отправка email на localhost`e

Tags: python, django, smtp

Подскажите, каким образом я могу отправить письмо на почтовый ящик на локальном сервере.
джанго работает на localhost:8080
для отправки (как прочитал в документации) нужен SMTP сервер. Запускаю тоже локальный

```
python -m smtpd -n -c DebuggingServer localhost:1025
```

получаю localhost:1025
во вьюхе

```
send_mail('theme', 'my messege', 'admins@studio.ru',
['a@a.ru'])
```

ловил разные ошибки, например с getaddrinfo(host, port)
добавил во вьюху

```
import socket
socket.getaddrinfo('localhost', 8080)
```

сейчас ошибка [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed

```
(code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
```

я вообще не знаю как настраивать (новичек) и написал в сеттингс:

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'localhost:8080'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'username@domain.ru'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = ''
EMAIL_PORT = 1025
```

у верен в сеттингс проблема. Подскажите как все правильно настроить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для разработки мне подходит решение в одну строчку. Все отправленные письма будут просто выводится в консоль(stdout).

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
```

Если вам все же необходимо настроить работу почты через отправку сервером.
Запускаем питоновский почтовик

```
python -m smtpd -n -c DebuggingServer localhost:1025
```

В файл настроек приложения

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'localhost'
EMAIL_PORT = 1025
```

Всё :)

Подробнее:

- [Ссылка на документацию](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/email/)
- [Stackoverflow Test sending email without email server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4642011/test-sending-email-without-email-server)