# Отправка почты из Django с localhost

Tags: python, django, email

Разбираюсь с Django, нужно потестить отправку писем на *реальные* emailы.
Про настройки Джанго в целом понял. [Здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/476499/django-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-email-%D0%BD%D0%B0-localhoste) есть кое-что, но это про отправку **на** все тот же localhost.
А как отправлять **с localhost** на настоящую почту? Возможно ли это вообще?
Что указывать при регистрации в том же яндексе?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Все, понял, может кому понадобится!
Достаточно использовать свой частный аккаунт в почте:

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.yandex.ru'
EMAIL_PORT = 465
EMAIL_HOST_USER = "любая реальная почта яндекса"
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = "ваш пароль от этой почты"
EMAIL_USE_TLS = False
EMAIL_USE_SSL = True
SERVER_EMAIL = EMAIL_HOST_USER
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = EMAIL_HOST_USER
```

При этом на другие мэйлы доходит через раз, но это уже отдельная проблема (борьба со спамом), о которой есть материалы